# HTML.ActionLink to Controller using Ajax to prevent postback

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

Here is the ASP MVC code in my view. It fires off to the controller and passes assetId and relationshipContext:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Archive", "Archive", new { assetId = Model.ID, relationshipContext = assetTypeRelation.RelationshipContextID }, new { @class = "btn btn-mini btn-warning", id = "btnArchive" })
```

I am wanting to utilize Ajax with this HTML.ActionLink, but am a bit confused. Here is the jQuery I have started with. Basically I just need this actionlink to pass assetId and relationshipContext to the Archive method in my assetcontroller.

```
$('#btnArchive').click(function(){
                  $.ajax({
                      url: '@Url.Action("Archive", "Archive")',
                      type: 'POST',
                      dataType: 'json',
                      data: {
                          assetId: $(this).attr("assetId"),
                          relationshipContext: $(this).attr("relationshipContext"),
                      },
                      success: function(){
                          alert("success")
                      },
                      error: function () {
                          alert("error")
                      },

                  });
```

Comment: I didn't recognize that language at the top. I did a Google search and found it was part of asp.net, specifically the mvc part. I added the asp.net-mvc tag, but you might want to add a bit of explanation to the code.

Comment: You want to mix server and client side codes.

Comment: Thanks for adding the additional tag, I updated the body of my question.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at @Ajax.ActionLink

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink(v=vs.108).aspx

Answer (score 0):

What does your AssetController action method look like? I should look something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Archive(int assetId, string relationshipContext)
{
     //do some work
     return Content("true");
}
```

Also, you are calling the wrong Controller in the @Url.Action call. Your View code might need to be changed to

```
$('#btnArchive').click(function(){
                  $.ajax({
                      url: '@Url.Action("Archive", "Asset")',
                      type: 'POST',
                      dataType: 'json',
                      data: {
                          assetId: $(this).attr("assetId"),
                          relationshipContext: $(this).attr("relationshipContext"),
                      },
                      success: function(data){
                          alert(data)
                      },
                      error: function () {
                          alert("error")
                      },

                  });
```